# how to eject cd drive in Ubuntu Vostro15

Tags: cd, drive

Curently my question is regarding Ubuntu Vostro laptop. I am unable to eject CD drive in my Ubuntu Vostro15. I tried to locate the eject button but was not able to locate any.

Comment: The Dell Vostro 15 Series laptops have a physical eject button on the drive. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

From command line you can use the command

```
eject
```

and the drive should open or throw out the cd/dvd.

You can add a device name (handy for when you have more than one drives) or a name too (like `eject cdrom` or `eject /dev/cdrom`).